# Why background-attachment local doesn't work on Android and IOS

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, mobile-safari

I'm trying to use background that scrolls with text area content, I found that background-attachment local do what I need, It works perfect on Chrome and Safari but when I tried it on IOS and Android devices It doesn't work, any idea how I can solve this issue, this is what I'm trying to do:

```css
.box{
    background: #ebebeb url("https://d1bys27s0mpm5v.cloudfront.net/static/images/underline.3bf1ed0760e9.png") repeat;
    background-attachment: local;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size:24px;
    font-family: CeraCY-Regular;
    padding: 4px;
    resize: none;
    border-radius: 1px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="box">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-attachment):

- Android Browser doesn't support `local` at all.
- Chrome for Android only supports it when `border-radius` is set
- Safari for iOS only supports it when  `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` is not used

In short, it's a cutting edge feature and support isn't entirely there yet.

Comment: So what's the alternative solution for this issue, how can accomplish this requirement?

Comment: Apparently it's still cutting edge in 2021 :\